Estimate SD[Z=X*Y] which one is correct?
Given we have a sample of two variables X and Y with sample size n. I want to calculate the standard deviation of Z = X*Y. I don't know which of the two options bellow are correct?
Option 1:
Simply create new variable Z=X*Y from sample, then using ordinary standard deviation formula:
$$ std(Z) = \sqrt \frac{\sum (Z-E[Z])^2}{n-1} $$
Option 2:
Using: $\text{Var}[X \cdot Y] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] \cdot \text{Var}[Y] + \mathbb{E}[Y^2] \cdot \text{Var}[X] + 2 \cdot \text{Cov}(X, Y) \cdot \mathbb{E}[X] \cdot \mathbb{E}[Y]$
Then estimate every components on the RHS and obtain std(Z)

Why can't both be correct?  Have you tried them both out on a simple example to see?  BTW, your formulas are contradictory: the first concerns a dataset and the second is a theoretical formula for random variables.  How do you propose applying it to data?
